# Is there a way to create cumulative sums with survey data with category labels in Python?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to calculate the cumulative sum of survey data that has category labels associated with each question.

For instance the statements below are on a 1-5 scale.

1. I relax myself at practice to get ready
2. When I need to, I can relax myself when I get anxious
3. I can increase my energy to just the right level for competitions.
4. I practice a way to energize myself.
   etc ...

When the data is returned, it is arranged in a dataframe:

```
    Date                Name            Sport       1. I relax myself at ...    2. When I need to ..
    12/7/2019 6:37:30   Joe Smith       Tennis      5                           1   
    12/7/2019 8:23:19   Jack Smith      Tennis      2                           5
```

I have a dictionary created with the question number (key) and category (value):

```
{
  1: 'RELAXATION'
  2: 'RELAXATION'
  3: 'ACTIVATION'
  4: 'ACTIVATION'
...
}
```

My thought was to use my dictionary as a look-up for what question was associated with what category. Then add the create a running sum for each athlete and for each category (e.g. RELAXATION, ACTIVATION, etc)

I could write a bunch of `if` statements (e.g. columns 5,10,22,23,35 = RELAXATION, columns 5,11,25,34,65 = ACTIVATION) but thinking there is a more pythonic way to do this.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

**UPDATE: easier to read data frame and dictionary**

```
In [26]: df
Out[26]:
   0       Date        Name   Sport  1. Q1  2. Q2  3. Q3  4. Q4
0  1  12/7/2019   Joe Smith  Tennis      2      5      2      5
1  2  12/7/2019  Jack SMith  Tennis      5      3      2      4

In [27]: lookup_dict
Out[27]: {1: 'RELAXATION', 2: 'RELAXATION', 3: 'ACTIVATION', 4: 'ACTIVATION'}

In [25]:
```

**What I'm looking for is:**

```
In [31]: df1
Out[31]:
        Date        Name   Sport  RELAXATION  ACTIVATION
0  12/7/2019   Joe Smith  Tennis           7           7
1  12/7/2019  Jack Smith  Tennis           8           6
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? For example, a smaller version of your Pandas DataFrame/NumPy array/dictionary?

Comment: @NicolasGervais made an update above, thanks. Hope this is more clear.